# Best way to public download a full folder with amazon?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, directory

I'm doing a launcher (in C#) that downloads a full game or app. The app can be very large (i.e. 5GB) and I need to get it with the correct folder hierarchhy, so the same launcher can check if the user has the correct app or it needs to be repaired or updated.

I'm trying to do that with amazon s3 and CloudFront, but seems that I can only get objects and not the full folder of the app.
I also have stored the folder in an EC2, and that works fine, but seems that EC2 is not designed for that, so downloads are extremely slow.

Is there any amazon service to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in your application with the DownlodDirectory method in TransferUtility class in the .NET SDK.

You can read more about the DownloadDirectory method [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MTransferUtilityDownloadDirectoryStringStringString.html). By default I believe it only downloads objects in the root path, so don’t forget to do it recursively for sub-folders if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered zipping the files first? It solves alot of issues eg folder structure, compression and works great from s3 and cloud front. Its a common solution for this use case.

Comment: This isn't suitable for my use case. The launcher should be able to repair the app or upload it, so if we upload just one item, launcher will download only this item. If I zip the whole folder, users will have to download the whole 5 GB zip everytime the app updates